# Python access return tuple from imported function

Tags: python

Hi i'm having trouble trying  to access the values(tuples) from the function which i wrote in another file:

test.py:

```
from random import randint

def generate_eth():

    eth_address = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 6)])
    eth_private_key = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 6)])

    return eth_address, eth_private_key

def generate_evt():

    evt_address = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 6)])
    evt_private_key = ''.join(["{}".format(randint(0, 9)) for num in range(0, 6)])

    return evt_address, evt_private_key
```

Each function return 2 values which each are randomly generate string of 6 numbers

And on my main.py:

```
from test import generate_eth, generate_evt

eth_address, eth_private_key = generate_eth
evt_address, evt_private_key = generate_evt

print(eth_address)
print(eth_private_key)
print(evt_address)
print(evt_private_key)
```

When i tried to print it i got the following error:

> cannot unpack non-iterable function object

I think that i can access return tuple from function like so. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Call your function please.

Comment: oh that right my bad

Answer (score 1):

you need to do the following:

```
eth_address, eth_private_key = generate_eth()
evt_address, evt_private_key = generate_evt()
```

The `()` is missing.